# How to convert valid regexp to html pattern? Invalid character in character class

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I would like to convert valid regexp to html pattern.

Most likely due to new `v` [flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag) following [regexp is no longer valid](https://regex101.com/r/FffGHj/1): `^[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+([ -][a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*$` pattern and gives an error:

```
Pattern attribute value [a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+([ -][a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)* is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+([ -][a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*/v: Invalid character in character class
```

Is there a way to convert a valid regexp to pattern, something like `/^[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+([ -][a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*$/.source`?

If not, what do I need to change exactly?

Comment: `[ -]` => `[ \-]`